# Why is my global variable undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I don't get it why it  prints the value undefined on the console before the correct id.

I am trying to return the inserted id yet I get an "undefined" on the return, but the console shows the correct id.

```
VisaFam.dbs.addFamily = function(nom) {
    var db = VisaFam.dbs.db;
    var  family_id;

    db.transaction(function(tx) {


        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO family (nom) VALUES (?)",
            [nom],function(tx, results){
                family_id= results.insertId;     //i want to return this 
                console.log(results.insertId);   // this prints the correct value 

             });
     });


    console.log(family_id); // this shows undefined
     return family_id; // the return is thus "undefined"

     }
```

Comment: I/O calls happens async in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O calls happens async in js and you should get returned value either from callbacks or promises:

```
VisaFam.dbs.addFamily = function(nom, callback) {
    var db = VisaFam.dbs.db;
    var  family_id;

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO family (nom) VALUES (?)",
            [nom],function(tx, results){
                family_id= results.insertId;     //i want to return this 
                console.log(results.insertId);   // this prints the correct value 
                callback(results);
             });
        });
}
```

then call addFamily as:

```
addFamily(nom, function(response) {
    //handle response
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the full context of your program, but it seems that the `db.transaction` function is asynchronous. Because of this, the `console.log()` statement is running before the family_id variable has a value assigned to it.

To test this, you can change the line `var family_id;` to `var family_id = "test";`
Console should spit out "test" immediately.

To log the correct id you want, you need to move the `console.log()` call into the `db.transaction` function, which ensures the code will only execute after the value is set.

Comment: Thank you very much Brandon , i get it now .